# Change serial converter voltage from 5 V to 3.3 V using resistor

Tags: ttl

I have a USD-TTL converter which uses 5 V. Can I change the output voltage from 5 V to 3.3 V using a resistor? Product: [https://www.amazon.com/Breakout-USB-TTL-Module-Lilypad-ATmega328/dp/B01LQYO1AI/ref=mp_s_a_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1543742183&sr=8-2&pi=AC_SX236_SY340_QL65&keywords=lilypad+arduino+usb&dpPl=1&dpID=41-vghnWhkL&ref=plSrch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01LQYO1AI)

Comment: the vendor claims that only soldering is needed, but I see nothing obvious in the photos. ask them how,

Answer (score 2):

[image: photo of ftdi breakout board from SparkFun that demonstrates where to solder the jumper for 3.3 volts]

Notice the last line in the feature description of the product. It says that it is convertible to 3.3 folds of required soldering. There are FTDI-TO-USB boards with a jumper header that can be selected between 5 volts and 3.3 volts for just as cheap which I would consider buying if you haven't already bought this one.

For this one you're going to have to look at the board for the jumper that you will have to solder and that connects the 3.3 volt output from pin 17 to the power output header. Currently your power output is coming from the chip PIN 20, 5 volts output, or as it is written in the schematics the VCC (as VCC and Vout are the same if 5v)

[image: jumper on schematic from Sparkfun ftdi breakout board]

[image: Power jnout from USB on Sparkfun FTDI Breakout board showing 3.3v flows to pin 17 and 5v is Vcc]

the chip itself is being run off of five volts you're just out putting data at 3.3 volts. So there is a way to switch what Voltage level is connected to the power output of the ftdi breakout board you have.

It seems like you're going to have to cut a solder only jumper under the soldermask with a razor to disengage the 5-volt output and then right next to that disengaged jumper, the jumper that you just cut, will be the 3.3 volt jumper that you have to solder like the 5v jumper was originally. In the pictures of your device that silk screen is all black & the jumpers appear to have been painted over but perhaps they have not been...

I imagine that they are in the same location as they are on all the other ftdi breakout boards so you could look at spark funs website for directions on how to do it.

[image: feature description from amazon listing on website]

Comment: Are you using voice recognition to dictate your text?  You've got odd words in there.  Like "night" for "volts."

Comment: @JRE fixed my voice2text errors.

Comment: Ok.  Cool.  They were just such odd errors.  If somebody writes "vilts" for "volts" it's an obvious typo.  "Nights" for "volts" was just so strange.